# provide a dialog to use browser inherent fullscreen on webapplications

Tags: javascript, browser, fullscreen, webgl

Is there a way to trigger a dialog to use browser built in Fullscreen? (And to leave fullscreen) (e.g. the mode of view that is usually accessible via f11)

Question Parameters:

I have a webGL webapplication where a common case of use is browsing the app for more than 10 minutes intensively.
During that time i would love to suggest fullscreen to users - so that the UI isn't interupted by browser differences and can use the most screen estate possible.

(There are several ways to create pop ups in Fullscreen - but that doesn't work on all browsers. In the best case: Non-modal Javascript accessable API to the browser functionality)

Chrome, Firefox, Opera, (IE) - solutions in that order of importance.

Please don't discuss question parameters if it can be avoided. Unless there is something important i have missed. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are standards in the works, but don't count on that for another year or two... Standards approval are very slow. This is in part related to mouse locking, which is a nice feature being implemented currently on Chrome by Vincent Schieb from Google.

If you want to test the Fullscreen API working on Nightly Webkit browsers (e.g. Chrome Canary) here's the Javascript code that will make your page go fullscreen:

```
function fs() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("test");
    elem.onwebkitfullscreenchange = function () {
        console.log ("We went fullscreen!");
    };
    elem.webkitRequestFullScreen ();
}
```